# Generate all unique items in a list using right shift bitwise operator

Tags: arrays, algorithm, bit

I'm trying to understand some code from MIT's online course that uses the rightshift bitwise operator to generate all unique combinations of a list

```
# generate all combinations of N items
def powerSet(items):
    N = len(items)
    # enumerate the 2**N possible combinations
    for i in range(2**N):
        combo = []
        for j in range(N):
            # test bit jth of integer i
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(items[j])
        yield combo
```

I understand that the lift `if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:` shift the bit right N times for an integer and looks at whether the last bit is 1 and then adds it the the list of unique combinations. However, I'm not sure how this generates all unique set in a list. Can anyone explain this in plain English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key of this algorithm is the fact there are 2**N different combinations of N items possible. This is quite easy to understand: we can either take an item or not, for every item; assume set of N items has M different combinations, then adding an item to the set makes 2*M combinations possible.

But this "yes/no" state of an item in a combination reminds strongly of bits (or, actualy, binary representation of a number). In case we have 2 items, we could write all the combinations as following.

```
00
01
10
11
```

Now, to generate all combinations, we just invert this process: we loop through numbers from 0 to 2**N-1, and look, what combination corresponds to it. Say, for the number 2 (or 10 in binary representation) the combination would consist of only one item with index 1. I.e. we are looking on the binary representation of current number (`i` in the code above), and are looping through it's digits, testing, if the j-th digit is 1 (`(i >> j) % 2 == 1`). If so, we add an item to the combination.